# Template Parse Errors not matching HTML

Tags: angular-material

I have been using mdTooltip and was running into issues so I am in the process of using MatTooltip in my project. When I run my app tho, I keep getting the following error

```
    core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'mdTooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("ass="form-control" (blur)="submitAnswer(item.$key, updatedata.value)"
                             [ERROR ->][mdTooltip]="item.desc"
                             mdTooltipPosition="right">
                   "): ng:///OwnershipCostModule/OwnershipAdminComponent.html@133:29
```

but when I go to where it tells me to I have the following

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="input-prepend input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
    <input type="number" #updatedata [placeholder]="item.amount" [value]="item.amount" id="default" name="default" class="form-control" (blur)="submitAnswer(item.$key, updatedata.value)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div> -- line 133
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error as I replaced all instances of mdTooltip in my project.

Edit: This is what the submitAnswer function looks like

```
submitAnswer(key: string, answer: number) {
    if (answer) {
       this.answerdata.update(key, { amount: answer });
    }
  }
```

answerdata is a FirebaselistObservable

Comment: What does your `submitAnswer()` function look like?

Comment: I added the submitAnswer() function to the question

Comment: Search your code for `[mdTooltip]="item.desc"` - it must be in your code somewhere but maybe not where you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was looking at the wrong component, and was able to get rid of the template parse error.